# MFC / Visual c++ : Toggling the visibility of a group box

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am a newbie in MFC have a simple group box having 4 radio buttons in it. I want to display this group box based on a toggle button anyone elaborate how to do it? It has to be done in visual studio using MFC

Comment: You need to elaborate. The question is unclear. [Edit] your question.

Comment: A [group box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-group-boxes) doesn't have any controls *"in it"*. The grouping is visual only. The group box and the controls it surrounds are siblings. At any rate, the visibility of a window is controlled using [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that your dialog looks something like:

[image]

1. Make sure your group has a dialog control ID. In this case, IDC_MY_GROUP.
2. Add a button click event handler for the Visibility button and one helper function that will toggle the visibility:

   ```
   void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonToggle()
   {
       ShowHideControls(GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_GROUP)->IsWindowVisible());
   }

   void CMFCApplication2Dlg::ShowHideControls(BOOL hide)
   {
       GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_GROUP)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);   
       GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO1)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
       GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO2)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
       GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO3)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
       GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO4)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
   }
   ```

Comment: I have another query related to this:

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider voting/accept it as the best answer.

Comment: I have another query related to this:
I am trying to switch between two group boxes depending upon the button click Toggle Visible, say Case 1 toggle Visible  button shows text TO BOX A and on clicking it showed Group Box A with it's set of buttons and the Toggle Visible Box contents changes to something like TO GROUP BOX B and on clicking that it shows box B with its content and the process continues.
@EyIM can you suggest something on this ?

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. Please post it as a separate question with the relevant code so the community will be able to help you.

Comment: @EyIM Query posted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444916/mfc-how-to-display-two-group-boxes-alternatively-based-on-a-button-click