# MFC : How to display two group boxes alternatively based on a button click?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have two group boxes containing 2 radio button each refer figure. I need a mechanism wherein the init stage value of button1 shows text "Group box 2" and the current group box displayed on the dialog is group box 1. 
As I click on the radio button1 = Group Box 2 currently the following happens:

1. The text in button 1 changes to group box 1
2. The group box 2 is displayed on the dialog
3. Group Box 1 is hidden

I know how to hide the group boxes what I am not sure is the toggling part
   [image: Group boxes with radio buttons]

Comment: *"Toggling"* is the operation of switching between a set of states, 2 in this case (*"visible"* and *"not visible"*). To toggle visibility, you transition to *"not visible"*, if the current state is *"visible"*, and vice versa. [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) allows you to set the visibility, and [IsWindowVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible) allows you to query the current visibility state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:
Create a function that will show/hide the relevant group box and update the text on the button.

1. You can use this function to show/hide the controls and the group. The parameter received are the IDs of the radios and the group box.

   ```
   void CMFCApplication2Dlg::ShowHideControls(BOOL hide, int groupID, int radio1ID, int radio2ID)
   {
       GetDlgItem(groupID)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
       GetDlgItem(radio1ID)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
       GetDlgItem(radio2ID)->ShowWindow(hide ? SW_HIDE : SW_NORMAL);
   }
   ```
2. Create a function that control the toggling:

   ```
   void CMFCApplication2Dlg::ToggleGroup(BOOL group1Visible)
   {
       ShowHideControls(group1Visible, IDC_MY_GROUP, IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO2);
       ShowHideControls(!group1Visible, IDC_MY_GROUP2, IDC_RADIO3, IDC_RADIO4);

       CString txt;
       txt.Format(L"Group Box %d", group1Visible ? 1 : 2);
       GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_TOGGLE)->SetWindowText(txt);
   }
   ```
3. Call the `ToggleGroup` from:

   a) `OnInitDialog` with FALSE parameter.

   b) In button click event handler.